# Spreadsheet Gem, upload and read file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet

I'm trying to upload and read a file using spreadsheet, with an absolute path, I can read the file, but when I try upload the file, I can't read it. What I can read the file?

```
def upload
  file_data = params[:uploaded_file]
  #book = Spreadsheet.open('/Users/MyMac/Downloads/issues.xls')
  book = Spreadsheet.open(file_data)        
  sheet1 = book.worksheet('Sheet1') # can use an index or worksheet name
  sheet1.each do |row|
    #TODO       
  end
end
```

Comment: you code malformed, please fix.

Comment: @PhilidorGreen done! the code is formatted.

Comment: What error did you get? And what path do you use to read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question should help you. You haven't stated which gem you are using to read the spreadsheet, but Spreadsheet and Roo should both serve your purposes.

[Parsing XLS Spreadsheet in Rails using Roo Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596138/parsing-xls-spreadsheet-in-rails-using-roo-gem)